# Move files into folders in batches of five?

Tags: windows, batch-file

Suppose I have 50 files sorted by name.. I would like to create a batch script which gives me the following result:

```
Files 1 through 5 -> 01-05
Files 6 through 10 -> 06-10
```

and so on..How can I create a batch script to achieve this?
Note that 01-05 and 06-10 are directory names..

EDIT: Details

For eg. Consider this:

> - Source Directory:
>
>   - 101.mp4
>   - 102.mp4
>   - 103.mp4
>   - 104.mp4

and so on..

I want a resulting directory structure like this:

> - Destination Directory:
> - 101-105:
>
>   - 101.mp4
>   - 102.mp4
>   - 103.mp4
>   - 104.mp4
>   - 105.mp4
> - 106-110:
>
>   - 106.mp4
>   - 107.mp4
>   - 108.mp4
>   - 109.mp4
>   - 110.mp4

and so on..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you want, change `fileCount` to change the file number in each subdirectory:

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set fileCount=5
set filesNow=0
set nameStart=000
set nameEnd=000
FOR /F "usebackq delims=" %%i IN (`dir /b /O:N *.mp4`) do (
    set /a filesNow+=1
    set /a tmpValue=filesNow %% fileCount
    ::echo !filesNow!
    ::echo !fileCount!
    ::echo %%i
    ::echo !tmpValue!
    if "!tmpValue!"=="1" (
        set "nameStart=%%~ni"
        mkdir _tmpDir_
    )
    move %%~nxi _tmpDir_\
    if "!tmpValue!"=="0" (
        rename _tmpDir_ !nameStart!-%%~ni
    )
    set "nameEnd=%%~ni"
)

if exist _tmpDir_ rename _tmpDir_ %nameStart%-%nameEnd%
```

You need to put them inside a bat/cmd file to work.
`filesNow` is for file number count.
Basically it's create a tmp folder and move files inside,
When files inside it reach the number, change the folder's name.
Several testing `echo` command I didn't remove, just used `::` to comment them out, you can remove the :: to test them again.

Comment: `/O:N` is a type of default option for `dir`; no need to use it!

Comment: @double-beep  Thanks for point out. However I guess there's no harm to keep it either, and might as well remind others to change/use it in the future :)

Comment: @double-beep, I wouldn't describe `/ON` or `/O:N` as a type of default option, but more that `NTFS` is more likely the default formatting option.

Comment: @double-beep As a default may be set temporary/permanently with the environment variable `dircmd` (here `dircmd=/ogn`) absolutely nothing is to say against explicitly using `/O:N`